# Transpose types variadicly

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variadic, variant-type, constrained-templates

I want to do template metaprogramming to compute the conversion from `std::variant<Ts...>` to `std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>`

I came up with something that worked

```cpp
template <typename T>
requires std::is_specialization_of_v<T, std::variant>
struct type_transpose {};

template<typename... Args>
struct type_transpose<std::variant<Args...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<std::vector<Args>...>;
};
```

which can be used as

```cpp
using Input = std::variant<float, int>;
using Result = type_transpose<Input>::type;
using Correct = std::tuple<std::vector<float>, std::vector<int>>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Correct, Result>);
```

Is this the best way achieve this type computation? Is this the only way?

I don't know template metaprogramming and was lucky to get anything working...

Full use case: https://godbolt.org/z/GoxzY59Px (I'm not asking to review the code in the link)

---

I called this transposing because the templates are equivalent to the `std::vector<std::tuple<Ts...>>` -> `std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>` operation. But what is a better name for this `std::tuple<Ts...>` to `std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>` operation? It's like we are mapping the `std::vector` type constructor/Functor over `std::tuple<Ts...>` a functor domain (sorry for by small my category theory vocabulary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the best way achieve this type computation? Is this the only way?

For this case where there is template specialiation, yes, I think this is the only way. You could add the following convenience alias though:

```
template<typename T>
using type_transpose_t = type_transpose<T>::type;
```

> I don't know template metaprogramming and was lucky to get anything working...

Congratulations, you do now! Note that it probably wasn't luck, but rather your intuition gained from "normal" programming, that you could apply to TMP.

---

I do think that the name is a bit misleading though. The word "transpose" implies you swap two things. So for example, a variant of vectors could get transposed to a vector of variants. Here you are creating a more efficient vector of variants (although some of the ordering will get lost). Maybe `to_tuple_of_vectors` would be a more correct name, even if it is a bit verbose.

Comment: "but rather your intuition gained from "normal" programming". Haha, I just looked through lots of implementations until I found one I thought I could steal from. Although, I do think all understanding comes from knowing lots of concrete examples and generalizing them. So what I did is the only way to proceed without understanding

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/284033/271531), this seems to be the only way to achieve what you want.

However, I can see a few places for improvement

1. An `std::vector<T&>` makes no sense however a `std::variant<T1&, T2&>` is possible. Since you are already using concepts. Condsider adding another concept that constraints `T` to be non-ref. You can alternatively convert a `std::variant<T1&, T2>` to `std::tuple<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T1>, std::vector<T2>>`.
2. Similarly, `std::vector<T const>` is not allowed. So, look into that.
3. Not sure, how applicable this is to your use case. But for completeness, consider adding another template parameter `typename Allocator` to your `type_transpose` struct and default it to `std::allocator<T>`. This is not easy and will require some metaprogramming wizardry.